# My Selenium tests run fine locally, but fail when I run them with Grid. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have several suites of about 10 Selenium tests written in Java. I'm using JUnit and some classes that I inherited that extend JUnit classes to run the tests in parallel.

The tests run in parallel just fine if I just use WebDriver without using Grid, but when I try to run the tests in Grid, some of the tests pass, but most fail, usually throwing a NoSuchElementException.

The reason I'm using Grid is so that eventually I can distribute testing, but also so that I can use a background service such as a PHP webpage to execute desktop processes on my Windows server.

I'm using Selenium 2.43.1. I sometimes execute the tests on my local machine using Windows 7, and other times on my server with Windows Server 2008.

I thought it might have to do with timeout settings for the hub or the node, so I start the hub like this:

```
cd c:\"Selenium Server"
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role hub -timeout 180 -browserTimeout 240
```

Comment: The way I got around this was by switching to TestNG. I was fortunate enough to have the freedom to do that, and I find that in general, it's more convenient.